# PHP ASCII Armored PGP encrypted string

Tags: php, gnupg

I need to PGP encrypt and ASCII armor a small string/token within a MediaWiki environment using a public key provided to me by a third party. This gives me:

- need to use PHP
- better to stay away from exec_shell() ... true?
- web server environment

I am planning to use GnuPG lib after reading this: 
http://devzone.zend.com/1278/using-gnupg-with-php/

What user should have PGP public key stored in their .gnupg folder?

---

**UPDATE 1**

so far I am testing hard-coding public key in (for now, just to test it out)

```
// GnuPG stuff
putenv("GNUPGHOME=/tmp");
$pubkey = "-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
Version: GnuPG v1.2.6 (GNU/Linux)
...key...
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----";

$ token="some text";
$gpg = new gnupg();
$gpg->seterrormode(gnupg::ERROR_EXCEPTION); 

try 
{
    $info = $gpg->import($pubkey);
//  var_dump($info); // to see fingerprint
    $info = $gpg -> addencryptkey("...fingerprint...");
    $enc = $gpg -> encrypt($token);
} 
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}


$token = urlencode($enc);
echo $token, "\n";
```

it seems to encrypt, now I just need to figure out if I need/can strip

```
Encrypted Data: -----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----
Version: GnuPG v1.4.5 (GNU/Linux)
```

as I am encrypting a token for a URL

Comment: Have you tried loading it using the `openssl` library? Can you provide an example of the public key you're using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ascii-armored output can be enabled using PHP's [gnupg-functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.gnupg.php). Have a look at [`setarmor`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gnupg-setarmor.php).

Add this line, probably best directly after creating your `$gpg` object:

```
$gpg -> setarmor(1);
```

But the documentation says ascii armoring would be default; what output do you get and which do you want? Sending ascii armored is convenient when mailing; otherwise you usually choose the smaller binary format directly. Never seen ascii-armored OpenPGP with "headers" stripped.

---

To your smaller questions:

> better to stay away from exec_shell() ... true?

If it is disabled anyway, there is no decision on that. As long as PHP's gnupg-functions have all functionality you need, prefer them; they save you from the hassle interfacing gpg (there is no direct API but the command line tools). Chance to introduce any exploits are smaller, too.

> What user should have PGP public key stored in their .gnupg folder?

Choose an arbitrary folder readable (possible not writable?) for the webserver but non-reachable using HTTP (so nobody will be able to fetch your keys). It seems you already realized how to setup this path.

> it seems to encrypt, now I just need to figure out if I need/can strip
>
> [snip]

I'd use some regex for this.

```
preg_match('/[\n\r]([=\n\r[:alnum:]]+)[\n\r]/', $token, $matches);
```

should do; maybe its more elegant to strip all lines either empty or containing a slash or colon.

Answer (score 1):

At a basic level, try the following code. It doesn't add ASCII armour, but it does turn it into a screen-friendly (non-binary) format that you could trivially armour yourself.

```
<?php
$data = 'Secret info';
$encrypted = null;
$ok = openssl_public_encrypt($data, $encrypted, $pubKey);

if ($ok) {
    // Optionally, encode it so you can echo it onscreen
    $encrypted = base64_encode($encrypted);
    echo $encrypted . "\n";
} else {
    echo "Failed to encrypt\n";
}
```

I don't know if you can import a PGP public key directly into OpenSSH, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57384/inter-convertability-of-asymmetric-key-containers-eg-x-509-pgp-openssh) might help you convert between key formats if you need to do so.