# PHP GnuPG segfaults in a webserver

Tags: php, gnupg

Inspired by http://devzone.zend.com/1278/using-gnupg-with-php/ and with help @ [PHP ASCII Armored PGP encrypted string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14267103/php-ascii-armored-pgp-encrypted-string)

I was able to GnuPG-encrypt a string with a 3rd party public key when running in CLI.

- set GNUPGHOME to world-readable location
- chmod keyring files to 666
- cli php encrypts the string just fine

---

```
PHP 5.2.10 (cli) (built: Nov 13 2009 11:44:05)
Copyright (c) 1997-2009 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2009 Zend Technologies
```

but...

I get "exit signal Segmentation fault (11)" when invoking **addencryptkey** running the same script through the webserver (Apache on CentOS).

apache errorl log

```
[notice] child pid 30682 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

nothing of value in syslog...

any pointers? thanks!

---

code (nothing earth shattering):

```
// GnuPG code
putenv("GNUPGHOME=/opt/.gnupg/");

$gpg = new gnupg();
$gpg->seterrormode(gnupg::ERROR_EXCEPTION); 
$gpg -> setarmor(1);

try 
{
    $info = $gpg -> addencryptkey("KEY");
    var_dump($info);
    $enc = $gpg -> encrypt($token);
    var_dump($enc);
} 
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

---

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Jan 14 11:29 .gnupg

[root@dev-lamp01 opt]# ll .gnupg/
total 28
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root 9224 Jan 14 10:23 gpg.conf
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root  325 Jan 14 10:25 pubring.gpg
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root    0 Jan 14 10:20 pubring.gpg~
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root  600 Jan 14 11:29 random_seed
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root    0 Jan 14 10:20 secring.gpg
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root 1200 Jan 14 10:25 trustdb.gpg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

oh well - my fault - as soon as I did

```
chmod -R 777
```

on my GNUPGHOME - it all worked

thought it was happy with 666 (and CLI was happy with just rw)

Comment: Don't give rights not needed. Sure your `$GNUPGHOME` was 666? You cannot open folder you haven't got exeecution rights on, so it must have been rights allowing you to open it, but not your webserver. Think about changing ownership to your user you're working on (lets discuss working as root or doing not somewhere else) and change the file's group to www-data (or whatever group your apache user is in), so you mustn't set it world-writeable. For the files inside, you should be able to set rights -1 on each file (if no a folder), as they all will not be executed, so you also don't need `-R` here.

Comment: Btw, great question and I probably wouldn't have had any clue on the answer. ;)

Comment: still fighting the permissions - gnupg refuses to work with anything less than 777. not giving up thou - thanks!

Comment: Do an `ls -l $GNUPGHOME` and `ps ax |grep apached` (provided that you're using apache). What users/groups are displayed?